# eclipse is not always compiling my release apk properly

Tags: android, eclipse

Sometimes when I export my APK to submit to google play. I upload to my device using adb, and the app just crashes immediately. I export again, without code or any other modification, and the compiled APK works fine. This happens randomly, as I have to compile and check if eclipse has properly compiled the APK. It always crashes when trying to find the Application class I set in the manifest file.

Recently a new thing started happening. The app starts but apk is improperly compiled. One of the classes is not there and when it's time to use it, my app just crashes. This too is random and is fixed by recompiling APK. Now its a huge issue, as I can't trust that the APK has been properly compiled anymore, even if it runs.

What could be the issue? And why is eclipse behaving this way? When running for debug, everything is always fine, and compiled correctly. I have roughly 5 library projects my main project depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug with the IDE or the ADT plugin. Update both and try again once.

Comment: It happens with fresh installs of Eclipse and Android SDK as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Proguard, it may be mangling some of the classes in your libraries. For example, if you reference a class only in `AndroidManifest.xml`, Proguard may not see the reference and could strip out the seemingly-unused class. The documentation for the library projects should address this, but the general approach is described in the [Proguard docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#configuring).

Comment: Recompiling randomly fixes the problem. If it was proguard I would expect it create a bad APK consistently.

Comment: There's going to be some randomness in the Proguard output due to the nature of what it does. Easy to check – try turning it off and rebuilding a few times. :)

Comment: I don't have 'proguard.config' set in any library project, or even my main project. From my understanding in this case proguard will not be enabled.